# How to listen for global action and update the rootState directly, while using multiple slices with Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, state, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I've got a state in my Redux store shaped like this:

```
type RootState = {
 PAGE_A: StatePageA,
 PAGE_B: StatePageB,
 PAGE_C: StatePageC,
 // AND SO ON...
}
```

Each page is a slice created with `createSlice` from `@reduxjs/toolkit`

I'm using Next.js static generation and SSR, so I need to hydrate my previously created store with the new state that comes form subsequent pages from the Next.js server.

Whatever page I'm routing to, I'll get the pre-rendered `pageState`, which should by of type `StatePageA | StatePageB | StatePageC`.

When that new state comes, I need to `dispatch()` a `HYDRATE_PAGE` action, which should replace the current page state.

This was my first idea on how to handle the `HYDRATE_PAGE` action.

```
export const HYDRATE_PAGE = createAction<{
  pageName: "PAGE_A" | "PAGE_B" | "PAGE_C",
  pageState: StatePageA | StatePageB | StatePageC
}>("HYDRATE_PAGE");
```

Then I would have to listen for it in every slice:

```
// EX: PAGE_A SLICE
// THIS WOULD HAVE TO BE DONE FOR EACH SLICE ON THE extraReducers PROPERTY

extraReducers: {
  [HYDRATE_PAGE]: (state, action) => {
    if (action.payload.pageName === "PAGE_A")
      return action.payload.pageState
  }
}
```

Is there a way where I can handle it in a centralized manner, without having to listen for that action in every slice reducer?

For example: a `rootReducer` kind of thing where I could listen for the `HYDRATE_PAGE` action and handle it in a single place like.

```
// THIS REDUCER WOULD HAVE ACCESS TO THE rootState
(state: RootState, action) => {
  const {pageName, pageState} = action.payload;
  state[pageName] = pageState;
};
```

Is this possible somehow?

---

**Extra**

There is this package called [next-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper), but I don't intent to use it. I'm trying to build my custom solution.

Comment: You could create a custom combineReducers function which handles it.  I can type out some code in a few hours.

Comment: @LindaPaiste That would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Overview of Concept

I'm not sure that your store has the best design because generally you want data to be organized by what type of data it is rather than what page it's used on.  But I'm just going to answer the question as it's presented here.

A reducer is simply a function that takes a state and an action and returns the next state.  When you combine a keyed object of slice reducers using `combineReducers` (or `configureStore`, which uses `combineReducers` internally), you get a function that looks like:

```
(state: RootState | undefined, action: AnyAction) => RootState
```

We want to create a wrapper around that function and add an extra step that performs the `HYDRATE_PAGE` action.

---

#### Typing the Action

```
export const HYDRATE_PAGE = createAction<{
  pageName: "PAGE_A" | "PAGE_B" | "PAGE_C",
  pageState: StatePageA | StatePageB | StatePageC
}>("HYDRATE_PAGE");
```

The typescript types that you have in your action creator aren't as good as they can be because we want to enforce that the `pageName` and `pageState` match each other.  The type that we actually want is this:

```
type HydratePayload = {
    [K in keyof RootState]: {
        pageName: K;
        pageState: RootState[K];
    }
}[keyof RootState];
```

```
export const HYDRATE_PAGE = createAction<HydratePayload>("HYDRATE_PAGE");
```

Which evaluates to a union of valid pairings:

```
type HydratePayload = {
    pageName: "PAGE_A";
    pageState: StatePageA;
} | {
    pageName: "PAGE_B";
    pageState: StatePageB;
} | {
    pageName: "PAGE_C";
    pageState: StatePageC;
}
```

---

#### Modifying the Reducer

First we will create the normal `rootReducer` with `combineReducers`.  Then we create the `hydratedReducer` as a wrapper around it.  We call `rootReducer(state, action)` to get the next state.  Most of the time we just return that state and don't do anything to it.
But if the `action` matches our `HYDRATE_PAGE` action then we modify the state by replacing the state for that slice with the one from our payload.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  PAGE_A: pageAReducer,
  PAGE_B: pageBReducer,
  PAGE_C: pageCReducer
});

const hydratedReducer = (state: RootState | undefined, action: AnyAction): RootState => {
  // call the reducer normally
  const nextState = rootReducer(state, action);
  // modify the next state when the action is hydrate
  if (HYDRATE_PAGE.match(action)) {
    const { pageName, pageState } = action.payload;
    return {
      ...nextState,
      [pageName]: pageState
    };
  }
  // otherwise don't do anything
  return nextState;
}

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: hydratedReducer,
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It should work. But regarding my state's shape, what about UI state? Wouldn't you organize it by page? That's the main reason I've split it into pages. I have multiple admin pages that have add/edit forms that handle different kinds of data and they mostly need async data from DB. So a page state would contain thinks like: loading and error status, form status (submission and validation errors), etc. How else would you organize it if not by page? Thanks again.